# Extracting sub-matrices from a matrix

Tags: matlab

I was wondering: I have a 100x100 matrix. I would like to split it in several 10x10 sub-matrices the first including columns and rows 1-10, then second including columns 11-20 and rows 1-10 and son on until eventually I have a set of 10x10 matrices.

Is there any way of doing this without needing to build an extremely complex array of for loops?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean [something like mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to divide an image into blocks in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab) or [Divide a matrix into submatrices in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554522/divide-a-matrix-into-submatrices-in-matlab). Honestly speaking, I hardly see any research effort at all. A simple Google search would've yielded a lot of helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract the sub-matrices **explicitly** than `mat2cell` would be a reasonable choice:

```
sm = mat2cell( M, 10*ones(1,size(M,1)/10), 10*ones(1,size(M,2)/10) );
```

However, if you only need these submatrices for a local processing you can use `blockproc`

```
blockproc( M, [10 10], @myFun );
```