# Splitting an image into blocks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new to Matlab and right now, I'm trying to split an image into NxN blocks as shown in an example below.

[image]

In matlab, I'm currently trying something:

```
my_image = imread('cat.jpg')
figure, imshow(my_image)

nrow = 12; %12 by 12 blocks as shown in the example above.
ncol = 12;

for i =1:nrow
    for j=2:ncol
       block = ...
    end
end
```

But I'm not entirely sure on how am i supposed to get those lines on the image. I've googled on this but non of them matches what I'm trying to get. Could anyone demonstrate on how is this done?

Comment: So you want a grid displayed over the image, rather than actually splitting your image? A simple `hold on` will hold the plot for you, allowing to plot the lines on top of the image

Comment: @Adriaan big discovery. Apparently the picture shown above is just a visual representation of the image behind the process of being split into NxN blocks. If so, how do I actually split the image into NxN blocks so that I could work with each blocks independently? Is the code partial code I written on the right track?

Comment: Your code is vague and general enough to say that yes, it is on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. Matlab's array indexing already supports retrieving and modifying subblocks.

For example, the 2nd 12x12 block is

```
my_image(1:12,13:24,:)
```

(I assumed 1 extra dimension for color. I'll let you handle the colors.)

You do not want to re-create the blocks unless you need both the original and the partitioned ones for computation. As much as possible, you want to let Matlab handle the copying and memory allocation.

If you really really need to generate the subblocks explicitly, see [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554522/divide-a-matrix-into-submatrices-in-matlab).

> I've googled on this but non of them matches what I'm trying to get.

When you Google, you want to Google the most generic and core concepts. What is an image in Matlab? It is a matrix. What you need is to search how to split a matrix into subblocks. Along this line, search any possible phrase that describes the concept and you will see tons of examples in search returns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the idea below without the third dimension.

```
M = magic(4);

N = 2;

x = 1:N;
y = 1:N;

[ X, Y] = meshgrid( x, y);

X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);

ind = sub2ind( size(M), X, Y);
ind = sort(ind);

subM = M(ind);
subM = reshape( subM, [N N])
```